# How to prevent MacVim from inheriting .profile as if it was Bash itself?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, macvim

I have this guard in my `.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi

    if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bash_aliases"
    fi
fi
```

Still, I have verified the check is passing for MacVim started from Finder, not only from bash terminal, and `.bashrc` contains terminal related script that seems to make MacVim not work as expected when started by double click, so I must have this check failing for non-terminal executions. I'm not sure whether this affects MacVim only or just any application. I was expecting `$BASH_VERSION` empty for anything started from Finder.

Any tips?

Comment: you might be better of asking that question on http://superuser.com/

Comment: [by debugging](http://superuser.com/questions/770137/how-to-prevent-macvim-from-inherenting-profile-as-if-it-was-bash-itself#comment999422_770137) I choosed to start using `$TERM_PROGRAM` instead of `$BASH_VERSION` in OS X now, this one works.

Answer (score 3):

There is a preference in MacVim to do this.

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMLoginShell 0
```

Comment: I'm selecting this as an answer since it address the problem for MacVim although I'll keep employing my solution which fits better for my intentions.

Comment: keep in mind that if you use MacVIm (GUI Mode) that i uses ~/.gvimrc if there or else it uses the gvimrc integrated inside of MacVIm.